# Issues with setTimeout

Tags: jquery, animation, svg, gsap

I am using TweenLite to complete some SVG animations, but for some reason every time i reload the page, the first time I hover the element with the animation, the durration of the animation is instant. Then after the first time the hover effect is added instantly, the animation works properly.

[CodePen](http://codepen.io/Zlerp/pen/adEZzE)

Just reload the page, hover the object and you will see the error I am receiving.

```
  $('svg').hover(function() {
    /* Stuff to do when the mouse enters the element */
    var currentCirc = $(this).find('.social-circle');
      currentCirc.stop()
      .animate({'stroke-dashoffset': 0}, 1000);
      TweenLite.to(currentCirc, 1, {fill:'rgb(144, 17, 133)'});
      console.log('on');
  }, function() {
    /* Stuff to do when the mouse leaves the element */
    var currentCirc = $(this).find('.social-circle');
      currentCirc.stop()
      .animate({
        'stroke-dashoffset': 900
      }, 1000);
      TweenLite.to(currentCirc, 1, {fill:'none'});
      // .css('fill', 'none');
  });
```

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is not in the javascript, but in the CSS. The `.social-circle` class does not have a `fill`, which means it is actually `#000`.

```
.social-circle {
    stroke-dasharray: 900;
    stroke-dashoffset: 900;
    fill: rgba(144, 17, 133, 0);
}
```

This [solves the initial animation](http://codepen.io/foozle/pen/zrpBmL), you may or may not have noticed that the 'fill'-animation uses a somewhat bright-colored transition from 'nothing' to the purple. This seems to be because TweenLite interprets `fill: 'none'` as `fill: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)` (the latter being transparent white, which in itself is not visible, but the steps in the transition are).
This is why I opted for the transparent version of your color in the code above.

Now that your question is answered, I feel like I should take some time to help you reducing the overall complexity of your solution.
The way I see it, you have used two different (and rather large) javascript libraries to achieve what should have been a very simple CSS declaration.

```
.social-circle {
    stroke-dasharray: 900;
    stroke-dashoffset: 900;
    fill: rgba(144, 17, 133, 0);
    transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s linear, fill 1s ease-in-out;
}
.social-circle:hover {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
    fill: rgba(144, 17, 133, 1);
}
```

With this style, you can drop *all* of the javascript, [as demonstrated in this pen](http://codepen.io/foozle/pen/BjJzML).

Comment: Thank you for your help! this works perfectly! Now i can throw out some of this JS.